# An array with variable value - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below, we can put **Sheet1 - Sheet4** in selection mode and copy.
But the point here is that the number of *Sheets varies*. Each time the file is changed, the number of Sheets is low or high. I just want to copy **Sheet1 .... n**, not all Sheets. (Every Sheet with the name of the **"Sheet"**.
How can this code be corrected for this issue?

```
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")).Copy
```

Comment: What is your goal ??  Do you want to copy ***ALL*** the sheets in a workbook ???

Comment: Explain your goal...

Comment: The text of the question was corrected. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub m()
    Dim nSht As Long
    ReDim shts(1 To Worksheets.Count) As String

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Name Like "Sheet*" Then
            nSht = nSht + 1
            shts(nSht) = sht.Name
        End If
    Next

    If nSht > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve shts(1 To nSht)
        Worksheets(shts).Copy
    End If
```

---

just for the record, here's the first solution spoiling

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name Like "Sheet*" Then
        If Not ActiveSheet.Name Like "Sheet*" Then sht.Activate
        sht.Select False
    End If
Next
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.Copy
```

Comment: I tested your code. If you are on sheets other than Sheet (e.g. S), then all the sheets are copied. Please try and report the result.

Comment: Actually there's the behavior you reported. It could be managed but it'd spoil the first solution "style". So see edited code for a more conventional solution

Comment: you are welcome. you can see edited answer for the first solution amended to cope with the case you noticed

Comment: @DisplayName nice solution.  I forgot about `Worksheet.Select False`.  I miss read the OP's post.